# Cannot link IBOutlet (with custom class set)

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, xib

In my class ViewController.h:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tv;`

ViewController.xib FilesOwner > Custom Class: "ViewController"

When I drag the connecting line from Files Owner to a tableview, nothing shows.

In FilesOwner > Outlets: There is view, dataSource & delegate for the tableview. There is no outlet for `tv`.

Why can I not link?

Comment: Please provide screenshots from your XIB.

Comment: Can you drag from the IBOutlet (the little circle in the left gutter in <ViewController.h>) to the tableview? Can you drag from the UITableView to the ViewController.h header file to create a new IBOutlet connection?

Comment: BTW: Current "best practices" are you don't put IBOutlets in headers; they should be in a category in the source file.

Comment: No, I cannot do either. What's wrong with headers?